# Batch to create a folder in a network folder

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've done a little batch that create a folder with the current date (year/month/day). 
This is the code:

```
mkdir %date:~-4,4%_%date:~-7,2%_%date:~0,2%
```

but it doesn't work when I use it in a network folder 
for exemple in "\192.168.1.100\01-SCHEMA"

What can i do? Thanks! :)
Dennis

Comment: Your can add UNC full path before the folder you want to create in your code. Use `\\192.168.1.100\...` instead of `\192.168.1.100\...`. For example, `md "\\192.168.1.100\...\your folder"`

Comment: `pushd` supports UNC paths, type `pushd /?` to find out how it works...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assign the network share a temporary drive letter and work on that:

```
NET USE Z: \\192.168.1.100\01-SCHEMA
mkdir z:\%date:~-4,4%_%date:~-7,2%_%date:~0,2%
NET USE Z: /DELETE
```

Or a bit easier, [let `PUSHD` / `POPD` do the same for you](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/pushd.mspx?mfr=true):

```
PUSHD \\192.168.1.100\01-SCHEMA
mkdir %date:~-4,4%_%date:~-7,2%_%date:~0,2%
POPD
```

Another possibility, from a now deleted comment, is to use the entire network path in the command:

```
mkdir \\192.168.1.100\01-SCHEMA\%date:~-4,4%_%date:~-7,2%_%date:~0,2%
```

**Update/Follow-up:** The general way in this situation - as asked - would be to evaluate all network shares and iterate over them. If you're sure that you **really** want to include **all** shares, use the code below (needs to be put in a `.bat` file). Use `NET VIEW \\192.168.1.100` to check the list of shares beforehand.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET HOST=192.168.1.100
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%G IN ('NET VIEW \\%HOST% ^| FINDSTR Disk') DO (
    MKDIR "\\%HOST%\%%G\%date:~-4,4%_%date:~-7,2%_%date:~0,2%"
)
```

**Follow-up #2:** In order to programatically create the folder over/on a network share independent of the actual network path, this single line will suffice:

```
MKDIR "%~dp0%date:~-4,4%_%date:~-7,2%_%date:~0,2%"
```

It works because `%~dp0`, which is expanded to drive letter and path of the currently running script, will give you the UNC-path if run from a network share. So this solution does more or less resemble method #3 of the first part of this answer.

Comment: Thank you very much!! :)
Is it possibile to have relative paths? I have that file in a lot of folders.. Have I to modify all of them with the assolute path or there is a faster and general way?
(I've it in \\192.168.1.100\01-SCHEMA , \\192.168.1.100\02-CALCOLO and so on)

Thanks :)

Comment: @DennisGrasso: Basically yes, but the problem is that the "directories" you want process are actually shares (`\\[HOST]\[SHARE]\[DIRECTORY]`). You need to get a list of those first. If you really want to create the directory **everywhere**, it's easy, otherwise things will probably get ugly quick.

Comment: @DennisGrasso: added a generic solution.

Comment: Hello @zb226 , thanks for your support! I didn't was too much clear..

This is the situation:
I've a server at //192.168.1.100
In this location I've a folder called PROJECTS
Inside it all my projects with a prefix number (ex. 9226_Hospital, 9227_School and so on)
When I have to create a new project I'll copy and past a general folder XXXX_PROJECT which I'll rename. Inside that folder I've my batch. In order to create the folder inside that, even when i rename the main folder. Is it possible without changing everytime the batch file?

Thanks!! :) Dennis

Comment: @DennisGrasso: now I understand your requirement. Updated the answer once more...

Comment: WOW thanks!! you're are awesome @zb226 ! One more little question: it works on folder without space in the name..
How to make it works on folder with spaces in the name?
(ex. \\192.168.1.100\01_Progetti\1_TRATTATIVE\IT.16.9002_Edificio residenziale - Arch. Mario Rossi)
Thank :))
Dennis

Comment: @DennisGrasso: You just need quotes around the path - Updated again... If everything works, you might want to accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

`E:\Test\New folder>mkdir "E:\Test\New Folder\""Creating Test Folder"`

Do not keep any space between **""**.