# Copy files from One Server to Another Server using Batch Command - Windows machine

Tags: windows, batch-file, server, xcopy, azure-vm

How to copy files from one server to another server(VM) using a windows batch command. ?

I have used below command

syntax : **xcopy** \\source_path \\serverIP\Destination_path /s /a /d

example : **xcopy** \\c:\repo\testproject \\10.101.101.11\C:\test\project /s /a /d

I'm getting the below error "Invalid drive specification" as of now.

1. Do I need to give credentials for accessing the VM ? If yes then where and how?
2. I have checked the destination path is correct.
3. Is there any other command should be used in that case ?

Comment: What is `\\c:\repo\testproject` supposed to represent? What is `\\10.101.101.11\C:\test\project` supposed to represent. Perhaps your issue is not related specifically to code but more to a lack of research or understanding of how to provide a server location?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Batch to create a folder in a network folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36892009/batch-to-create-a-folder-in-a-network-folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to give credentials for accessing the VM ? If yes then where and how?

If the passwords on the source and target machine are the same then no credentials are necessary, otherwise yes they will need to be provided.  Two solutions you can consider:

- Use "runas" and specify the credentials there
- Use the temporary network drive solution proposed in the comment by UserPo41085.  This solution uses the "net view" command which has credential parms.

> I have checked the destination path is correct.
> example : xcopy \\c:\repo\testproject \\10.101.101.11\C:\test\project /s /a /d

Both paths in the example provided are a mixture of standard "DOS" paths and UNC paths.  UNC paths reference a share name and not a disk letter.

The example in the link below copies a file on the local machine called zz_yuv.png to a machine called "ws9" which has a share called "c9.system" and the share is mapped to the root folder of the c: drive on ws9. If you are running an account which is a member of the administrators group you can use the admin shares...(admin$, c$ etc.)

[xcopy example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUCOH.png)

> Is there any other command should be used in that case ?

Robocopy is built into the later versions of windows. It does come with a learning curve but is much more robust than xcopy.   Just as a note, robocopy will be under the same types of credentialing restraints as xcopy - it just has more and better features for copying.

Comment: Ok. Changed to: learning curve...